# Can someone explain why I can't add an extra button to this ScrollView?

Tags: java, android, button, scrollview

This makes no sense. I have some code that has a simple LinearLayout and inside it there is a TextView and a ScrollView and inside the ScrollView there is a button. Well when I add the second button I get an error saying that ScrollView can only have one child. Is a Button considered a different child??? I'm sorry for my stupidity if this is really simple. If anyone can help THANKS!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:duplicateParentState="false"
android:fadeScrollbars="true"
android:gravity="center"
android:isScrollContainer="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:scrollbars="vertical">
<TextView 
    android:text="Select category:"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="100dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Food"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
            android:text="Food"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Clothing"
            android:layout_width="175dp"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/blackbutton"
            android:text="Clothing"
            android:textColor="#ffffff" />  
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ScrollView must have 1 child. So put the two buttons inside a layout.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is literally in the documentation of a [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html):

> A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in
>   it containing the entire contents to scroll; this child may itself be
>   a layout manager with a complex hierarchy of objects. A child that is
>   often used is a LinearLayout in a vertical orientation, presenting a
>   vertical array of top-level items that the user can scroll through.

In other words: you'll need to put the two buttons inside a layout of your choice, that on its turn is the sole child of the ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

put those two buttons inside a linear or relative layout.... and put that layout inside the scroll view. this should solve the issue.

Scroll view can only have one child control...